# Safely Importing Modules With Unicode Names in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.6, python-2.x

(Python 2.6)

I have some code that does some customization based on client name.

It does something like this:

`custom_module = __import__("some.module.company_inc")`

this works fine so long as our clients have ascii-only names.

I would like to make this code work correctly for non-ascii company names as well, e.g.

`custom_module = __import__(u"some.module.unicóde_company_inc")`

However, `__import__` only accepts bytes, so I need to encode this first.

Is `__import__(u"some.module.unicóde_company_inc".encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())` guaranteed to work on all systems (assuming that the filesystem encoding supports "ó" of course)? Is this the right way to do this? (Assuming I don't statically know the encoding that the box uses)

I am most interested in linux systems. (But it would be nice to know for non-linux as well)

Comment: Does it at least work on *your* system? It's always easier to prove a negative than a positive.

Comment: Of course. : ) I just don't know if it's the logically right way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it is possible that [`sys.getfilesystemencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding) can return `None` under some circumstances (e.g. if `LANG` is not set). So it would probably be slightly safer to fallback to "utf-8" to allow for that (rather unlikely) possibility:

```
    encoding = sys.getfilesystemencoding() or 'utf-8'
```

That will cover 99.9% of cases. For the rest, I would just allow the application to raise an exception (since that's exactly what it is), and then bail out gracefully with a suitably informative error message.

Comment: I did read this after I posted the question. I'll handle this. Thanks!